# Maven fails to download parent pom because it appends wrong version?

Tags: maven

When maven tries to build a project that includes dependency A, it fails because it can't find the correct version of the parent pom P.

Note that in this case, the child pom A is a different version from the parent. What I see in the logs is that it is trying to download the parent pom, but with the wrong version.

Child pom:

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>foo-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
```

In the logs, the build then shows:

```
 Failed to collect dependencies at org.foo:foo-bar:jar:3.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.foo:foo-bar:jar:3.0.1: Could not find artifact org.foo:foo-parent:pom:3.0.1 in nexus
```

I would've expected it to look for the pom of 3.0.0, not 3.0.1, which does exist in the remote (nexus).

Comment: Th artifact is available and it is downloaded okay - the build fails when trying to collect dependencies (i.e read the parent). In this case the child project was updated but the parent was not, hence the different versions. I accidentally left a bit off the error message, which I've added, but it doesn't make it any more clear to me whats going on.

Comment: Are you sure you did not accidentally define a dependency on the parent pom?

Comment: No, the parent looks fine. What confuses me more is that this was working as recently as yesterday - this morning the error started showing up, with no changes to the poms or build command.

Comment: Then please post the whole child pom